# How to encoding wordpress option before saving in DB

Tags: wordpress

some time ago I started practicing with Wordpress and today I am struggling with a problem on wordpress. Let's get to the problem:

1. I would like to filter the value from a form
2. Pass it through an encryption function
3. Finally save it in the database

This is my code:

```
apply_filters( 'pre_update_option_apikey', $encrypted, $old_value, 'apikey' );
add_filter('pre_update_option_apikey', 'encryptData', 10, 2);
```

This is the encryption function:

```
function encryptData($encrypted) {
                
    $config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    );

    $res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
    openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);
    $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
    $pubKey = $pubKey["key"];
    update_option('pkey', $pubKey,'','yes');

    openssl_private_encrypt($old_value, $encrypted, $privKey);
    
    return $encrypted;
    
}
```

Before writing here I read all the possible guides on the subject and did a lot of test, sorry but i don't understand where i'm wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean by encoding? What's happening right now? Do you get any errors/warnings?

Comment: I want to "catch" a value from a form, and encoding it before put it in the database. No errors, but empty options in the database.

Comment: You could use `$pubKey = urlencode($pubKey);` before updating the option, and then use `urldecode` when you retrieve the data from the database to get the encrypted value.